# Flex Client Authentication with NTLM using md5 encryption

Tags: php, apache-flex, md5, ntlm

I have flex client application with php as a server and i want to implements domain user and password authentication.
I'm sending the user and the password from the flex client through httpservice to php script and the php script authenticate the user and the password with the domain
But! I want to encrypt the user's password in flex and to decrypt it in the php.
I have the as3crypto.swc module for the flex but I don't find any way to decrypt it in the php.
So, how can I do that and If this is not the right way to do that how can I do that?
Any help?
Regards.
elad.

Answer (score 1):

The md5 encryption is considered a one-way encryption and does not have a related decrypt function.

The best way to handle this is to store the md5 encrypted password in your database, then make sure you encrypt any passwords with md5 before you send them to the server. At that point you can test the encrypted password you sent against the encrypted password stored in your database.

Comment: Hi, I want to send the user and the password to the LDAP server without storing them in any DB.